# How to find element from given array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array like `MyArr {1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10}`. I need to iterate and print `"Not Found"` till I reach 2. After that, I need to print `"Found"` for the remaining.

My approach is to use `Arrays.BinarySearch(MyArr,2)` which returns the index of 2. I have no idea how to achieve from here.

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: The method is called [`binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int[],%20int%29), not `BinarySearch`, and javadoc says: *The array must be **sorted**.* Your array is not sorted, so you cannot use `binarySearch`. Time for you to iterate the array yourself, which is actually is big part of your assignment.

Comment: Who says he needs to use binary search?  Just iterate over the array once be done with it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think anyone here did. That was OP's own idea. Hence I suggested the same thing (iterate, that is).

Comment: if even- and odd-numbers end at consecutive values like that, just print "not found" for `array.length/2-1` times then the rest.

Comment: binary search doesn't improve anything. gotta iterate to print not/founds.

Comment: @Roam How does that work? What if task is to reach 6? Or 5? --- For second comment, `binarySearch` isn't just "not an improvement", it actually **doesn't work**. Big difference.

Comment: doesn't work if array has no pattern. go for one of the answers given for the general case.

Comment: It's so easy. You should read documentation sometimes. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html.

Answer (score 4):

Binary search can't be used because it only works on sorted arrays.

You need to *iterate* over the array. For each element, you must check if it's your target value and have your code remember the result, *and* print the output appropriate for the value of the result.

Comment: `binarySearch` doesn't find the value, it finds the index, which would have been valuable, had it worked (sorted array), so your second bullet seems wrong.

Comment: Yay! I've killed 5 answers so far (by down-voting them). Finally an answer I can up-vote (guess because it mostly says the same as [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085335/how-to-find-element-from-given-array#comment61715180_37085335)?). It tells what is wrong, how to do it better, without giving away the solution. Yay!

Comment: @andreas I don't know what I was thinking :/.  Bullet deleted

Answer (score 0):

`binarySearch` only works for an input array that is sorted (in ascending order), and your input array isn't sorted.

Solution #1:

> Sort the array first.  Then `binarySearch` will find you the correct offset for the element in the sorted array.

**Hint:** look at the other methods in `Arrays`.

Note that **this is not the correct solution**.  The actual problem statement says that you need to step through the array, 1) printing "not found" for non-matching elements and 2) printing "found" when you find the first match.  Solution #1 only addresses the 2nd requirement, not the first one.

In fact, binary search cannot satisfy the first requirement.

<sup>Aside: sorting an array so that you can do a binary search ... just once ... is inefficient.  You spend more time sorting than is saved in searching.  In complexity terms, sorting will be `O(NlogN)` and searching `O(logN)` giving an overall complexity of `O(NlogN)`.  By contrast a simple linear search is `O(N)`.  Hence you will only "break even" if you do `O(logN)` binary searches for each sort.</sup>

Solution #2:

> Forget about binary search, and write a loop that steps through all of the elements of the array.

**Hint:** a `for` loop would be best, but which kind of `for` loop?

Comment: Sorting the array first would produce incorrect result. Solution should print `Not Found` 5 times, followed by `Found` 5 times. If you sort, the number 2 will be in a different position and output would be `Not Found` 1 time, and `Found` 9 times.

Comment: So 2/3 of your answer is a solution that cannot be used (sorting)?

Comment: Yes.  And it is useful for the OP to understand the reasons (plural!!!) why he can't / shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm just ornery at this late hour (3am), but your description of why not is off. You say "print `found` when you find the array", but it's supposed to be "print `Found` when you find the *value*, then print `Found` for the remaining". The entire point of *why* you cannot sort, is that it changes the *position* of the value you're looking for, which even makes your initial statement wrong: "`binarySearch` will find you the correct offset". It won't, because it wouldn't *be* the correct offset, and so it doesn't even address the 2nd requirement.

Comment: Disagree, but not enough to down-vote you, so I'll leave it neutral and go to bed. To totally kill a Star Trek quote: May you be friendly and helpful. *(more than me, for sure)*